# Jquery how to get value assigned inside a function

Tags: jquery

I have the following code, and I am assigning foobar inside the closure?? but I can't seem to get the value of out the scope.

```
var foobar; 
$("#something").change(function(){
    var foobar = $('#something').find(":selected").val();
});

foobar
```

Comment: dont redeclare it inside change event. change `var foobar = $('#something').find(":selected").val();` to `foobar = $('#something').find(":selected").val();`

Comment: Ah, I thought this was like php :) thanks. @guradio

Comment: no problem mate glad to help

Answer (score 4):

You already declared a variable outside it was fine . if you again declare it inside the function mean. so it can be accessed inside the function only  .

```
var foobar; 
$("#something").change(function(){
    foobar = $('#something').find(":selected").val();
 });

 console.log(foobar);
```

Answer (score 1):

Dont use `var foobar` inside closure. Use like this

```
var foobar; 
$("#something").change(function(){
    foobar = $('#something').find(":selected").val();
 });

 alert(foobar);
```

Answer (score 0):

define foobar outside the function.

```
    var foobar; 
$("#something").change(function(){
    foobar = $(this).find(":selected").val();
 });

 alert(foobar);
```